# When is a Flow User license needed?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a flow that is called from a Process Builder process when a record update meets certain criteria.  I need this flow to work whenever any of my users update the record.  Do they need flow licenses?  It doesn't seem like it.  I am confused about what the Flow User option on the user profile is for.